# <h:graphicImage> is not getting refreshed in JSF

Tags: java, jsf

I would like to display a graphic image in a jsf web application from a xhtml file that's changing for each run. I am displaying an image once the upload is done. But what happening is after uploading any image it always displays the one which I uploaded at first time. On doing refresh it displaying the recent uploaded image. Why it is always displaying an image I uploaded at first try. How could I display the most recent uploaded image with `h:graphicImage`. I am using servlet to display an image. Can anyone help me out...???

here is my code for displaying an image:

```
public void displayImage(byte[] image,HttpServletResponse response) { 
      ServletOutputStream out;
      if ( image != null ) {
      BufferedImage bufferedImage; 
           try {
                      bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image)); 
                out = response.getOutputStream(); 
                ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png",out);
           } catch (IOException e) { 
                logger.info("Exception in reading the image" + e);
           }
      } else {     
           logger.info("No bytes present ");    
      }
```

this is my actual requirement...
In first window I have signature box. In that I have upload button.Once the upload is done then I will show an window(2) with an uploaded image there i can crop the image such that I could save it on the signature box of the first window. it is working fine. But what happens when i cancel/close the 2nd window is the signature box of 1st remains empty. So user can upload some other image. In that case, when I try to upload an image, Its successfully getting uploaded but it is not displayed on 2nd window it still the shows the image which I uploaded at first try. How do i fix it...???

Comment: For uploading an image I am using primefaces. while uploading an image , i am extracting bytes of an image and then displaying it using servlet.

Comment: If you're already using primefaces, why don't you try with `<p:graphicsImage>` instead of using the servlet?

Comment: take a look at this http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/dynamicImage.jsf you better use it for display your images , just update the p:graphicImage after the file is being uploaded with update="" of upload component , but anyway , are you updating your <h:graphicImage> after the upload file is complete?

Comment: Yeah, Daniel is right. It won't show the latest image if you don't update the image component. That's why I suggested using PrimeFaces' image. Just give an id to your `<p:graphicsImage>` and add the `update="imageID"` to your `<p:fileUpload>`

Comment: I have some other purpose for using servlet in my application. I think browser caching problem is there here. that might be the reason for not displaying the recent uploaded image. cache has the image which I uploaded first. How do i clear it...???

Comment: Imo the problem is that you don't update your image after upload as @Daniel mentioned. If you really think that problem is in caching then try this in your servlet:         `if (!request.getRequestURI().startsWith(request.getContextPath() + ResourceHandler.RESOURCE_IDENTIFIER)) { // Skip JSF resources (CSS/JS/Images/etc)
            response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
            response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
            response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
        }`

Answer (score 3):

Tell the browser to not cache the image. Set the following headers on the servlet response before the first bit is ever written to its body:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

To prevent hard-nosed browsers from still caching it, add a request parameter with a timestampto the servlet URL.

```
<h:graphicImage value="imageServlet?id=#{bean.imageId}&amp;t=#{now.time}" />
```

Where `#{now}` is been registered in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>now</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```

Comment: I was using '<p:graphicImage>' and '<p:cropperImage>' and I had this issue. Below code fix this problem and now browser show picture in ajax submit. Thanks @BalusC