# Image not updated after clicking the ajax enabled command link

Tags: ajax, image, jsf, captcha

I am wrirting a captcha code for my jsf project. I have done almost everything but the problem is the refreshing og the image. I'd like to do it with ajax so that when I click the image, it be replaced by new one. But when I click it the image doesn't get updated. But it is updated after reloading the page.

```
<h:form>
    <h:commandLink>
        <h:graphicImage value="/captcha/test.png"
            style="width:35mm;height:2cm;" />
            <f:ajax render="@all" listener="#{captcha.recaptcha()}"></f:ajax>
            </h:commandLink>
            </h:form>
```

every time I click the image , it is changed on disk but not updated in the html page.
Thanx for any useful responses !

Comment: Is [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614239/hgraphicimage-is-not-getting-refreshed-in-jsf) related? Ie, please check in your browser's dev tools that it doesn't cache the image.

Comment: tha question is for servlets and I am using jsf not servlet.

Comment: Besides the fact that JSF is based on a Servlet, have you checked the browser actually issues a GET for the image?

Comment: I checked that the image is being changed by clicking the link but how can I check if the browser issues a GET for that image ?

Comment: You can use your browsers debug tools, typically accessible by pressing F12/F11. They have a "network" tab showing you what's really going on.

Comment: I did but no GET was issued there for the image. now what should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code using execute and render tags

```
<h:form>
   <h:commandLink>
      <h:graphicImage value="/captcha/test.png" style="width:35mm;height:2cm;" />
         <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" listener="#{captcha.recaptcha()}" />
   </h:commandLink>
</h:form>
```

Answer (score -1):

You have need to use update attribute.

take a look-

```
<h:form id="form1">
<h:commandLink>
    <h:graphicImage value="/captcha/test.png"
        style="width:35mm;height:2cm;" id="img1"/>
        <f:ajax render="@all" listener="#{captcha.recaptcha()}" update=":form1:img1"></f:ajax>
        </h:commandLink>
        </h:form>
```

Hope this will work

Comment: it doesn't work because f:ajax tag doesn't have any update attribute and its equivalent for that is render attribute.

Comment: Oh..my mistake.Use immediate="true"