# reload graphic in partial ajax submit?

Tags: spring, jsf, jsf-2, spring-webflow

My idea is upload a picture and show it updating just div (which contains the picture) with ajax as many times as necessary. I would like doing so because I use a view scope managed bean. I get success when I refresh (f5) view but never using ajax.

Above code is like a wizard, first I upload a picture, second I crop picture and third I show buttons to save cropped image or reupload a new picture and start again or recrop the original picture again.

I use JSF 2.2, PF 5, Spring 4 and SWF 2.4

First time I get through wizard works right and even though I update with ajax the picture is shown, but when I use wizard again then new picture is omitted and view show the old picture.

```
            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="finalConfigurationContainer" styleClass="finalConfigurationContainer">
            <h1>
                <h:outputText value="#{msg['configuration1.main.header']}" />
            </h1>

            <h:outputText value="#{msg['configuration1.main.msg']}" />


            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="addSpaceImgContainer"  styleClass="addSpaceImgContainer">
                <h:form>
                    <h:inputHidden value="#{pictureProvider.idRequest}"  />
                </h:form>


                <h:form id="uploadForm" rendered="#{pictureProvider.flagPicture}" enctype="multipart/form-data" prependId="false">
                        <p:fileUpload allowTypes="/(\.|\/)(jpe?g)$/" cancelLabel="#{msg['upload.cancel.msg']}" dragDropSupport="true" fileLimit="1"
                            fileLimitMessage="#{msg['upload.filelimit.msg']}" fileUploadListener="#{pictureProvider.handFile}" 
                            invalidFileMessage="#{msg['upload.invalidfile.msg']}" invalidSizeMessage="#{msg['upload.invalidsize.msg']}" 
                            label="#{msg['upload.label.msg']}" sizeLimit="5242880" mode="advanced" uploadLabel="#{msg['upload.upload.msg']}"
                            update="@all" />

                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="previewPictureContainer" rendered="#{selectedSpace.img or pictureProvider.flagPreviewPicture}" styleClass="previewPictureContainer">
                        <h:outputText value="#{msg['configuration1.preview.msg']}" />

                        <p:graphicImage cache="false" value="#{request.requestURL.substring(0, request.requestURL.length() - request.requestURI.length())}#{request.contextPath}/images/#{selectedSpace.idSpace}/coverPicture.jpeg" />

                        <h:commandButton action="recrop" value="#{msg['reuse.btn']}" alt="#{msg['reuse.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['reuse.btn.title']}" accesskey="4" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup  layout="block" id="cropperSpaceImgContainer" styleClass="cropperSpaceImgContainer">
                <h:form id="cropperForm" rendered="#{pictureProvider.flagCropper}" prependId="false">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="preRenderSpaceImgContainer" styleClass="preRenderSpaceImgContainer">
                        <p:imageCropper immediate="true" initialCoords="225,75,300,75" widgetVar="casas" value="#{pictureProvider.croppedImage}" image="#{request.requestURL.substring(0, request.requestURL.length() - request.requestURI.length())}#{request.contextPath}/images/#{selectedSpace.idSpace}/coverPicture.jpeg" alt="#{msg['cropper.picture.msg']}" />

                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="croppedButtonsContainer" styleClass="croppedButtonsContainer">
                        <p:commandButton update="@all" value="#{msg['crop.btn']}" action="#{pictureProvider.crop}"  icon="ui-icon-scissors"/>                       
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="saveCropImgContainer" styleClass="saveCropImgContainer">
                <h:form id="controlForm" rendered="#{pictureProvider.flagSave}"  prependId="false">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="renderSpaceImgContainer" styleClass="renderSpaceImgContainer">
                        <p:graphicImage cache="false" value="#{request.requestURL.substring(0, request.requestURL.length() - request.requestURI.length())}#{request.contextPath}/images/#{selectedSpace.idSpace}/tempCrop.jpeg" />
                    </h:panelGroup>

                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="saveCropButtonsContainer" styleClass="saveCropButtonsContainer">
                        <p:commandButton update="@all" value="#{msg['crop.btn']}" action="recrop" alt="#{msg['crop.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['crop.btn.title']}"  icon="ui-icon-scissors"/>
                        <p:commandButton update="@all" value="#{msg['save.crop.btn']}" action="#{pictureProvider.save(flowRequestContext)}" alt="#{msg['save.crop.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['save.crop.btn.title']}"  />
                        <p:commandButton update="@all" value="#{msg['reupload.btn']}" action="reupload" alt="#{msg['reupload.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['reupload.btn.title']}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>

            <h:panelGroup layout="block" id="omit1StepContainer" styleClass="omit1StepContainer">
                <h:form prependId="false">
                    <p:commandButton value="#{msg['omit.btn']}" action="omitPicture" alt="#{msg['omit.btn.alt']}" title="#{msg['omit.btn.title']}" accesskey="10" />
                </h:form>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </h:panelGroup>
```

**Bean code**

```
@Component("pictureProvider")
@Scope("view")
public class PictureProvider implements Serializable {


@Autowired
private ServletContext sc;

@Autowired
private ISpaceBO spaceBo;

public void handFile(FileUploadEvent event){
    logger.entry("PictureProvider.handFile()");

    String pathMultimedia=sc.getInitParameter("multimediaPath");

    RequestContext requestContext=RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
    Space space=(Space)requestContext.getFlowScope().get("selectedSpace");

    RequestControlContext rec = (RequestControlContext) requestContext;



    //Create multimedia folder
    File f=new File(pathMultimedia + File.separator + space.getIdSpace());

    if(f.exists()){
        logger.debug("Multimedia folder already exist");

        try{
            savePicture(event,f,this.getIdRequest(),space.getIdSpace());
        }catch (FacesException e){
            //return "error";
        }

    }else{

        //0777 permissions
        f.setReadable(true, false);
        f.setWritable(true, false);
        f.setExecutable(true,false);

        if(f.mkdir()){
            logger.debug("Multimedia folder was created");

            try{
                savePicture(event,f,this.getIdRequest(),space.getIdSpace());
            }catch (FacesException e){
                //Arreglar
                //return "error";
            }
        }else{
            //Arreglar
            //return "error";
        }
    }

    //Redirecting to transition, it's necessary to reload cropper
    //rec.handleEvent(new Event(this,"yes"));

    event=null;
}

public void savePicture(FileUploadEvent upload,File file,String idRequest,Integer idSpace){
    logger.entry("PictureProvider.savePicture()");

    InputStream data;
    byte[] bytes=null;

    try {
        data = upload.getFile().getInputstream();
        bytes=IOUtils.toByteArray(data);
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    String extension=upload.getFile().getContentType().replace("image/","");
    extension="." +  extension;

    FileImageOutputStream imageOutput=null; 
    String namePic=null; 
     try{

         switch (idRequest) {
            case "event":
                String nameEventFolder="E"
                        + spaceBo.getDao().countSectionPages(idSpace,4);
                File f=new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + 
                         File.separator + "events" + File.separator + nameEventFolder);

                if(f.exists()){
                    int totalFiles=f.listFiles().length;
                    namePic="pic_" + totalFiles + extension;

                    imageOutput=new FileImageOutputStream(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()
                            + File.separator + namePic));
                }else{
                    f.setExecutable(true,false);
                    f.setWritable(true, false);
                    f.setReadable(true, false);

                    if(f.mkdirs()){
                        int totalFiles=f.listFiles().length;
                        namePic="pic_" + totalFiles + extension;

                        imageOutput=new FileImageOutputStream(new File(f.getAbsolutePath()
                            + File.separator + namePic));
                    }
                }

                RequestContext requestContext=RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
                EventProvider eventProviderBean=(EventProvider) requestContext.getActiveFlow()
                                                                .getApplicationContext().getBean("eventProvider");

                //eventProviderBean.setTempFolderName(nameEventFolder);
                eventProviderBean.getTempPicNames().add(namePic.substring(0, namePic.indexOf(".")));


                //MARCAR ERRORES si no es un DIRECTORIO
                break;

            case "configuration":
                imageOutput=new FileImageOutputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath() + 
                         File.separator + "coverPicture" + extension));
            default:
                break;
        }

         if(imageOutput!=null){
             imageOutput.write(bytes,0,bytes.length);
             imageOutput.close();

             this.setFlagPicture(false);
             this.setFlagCropper(true);
             this.setFlagPreviewPicture(true);
         }


     }catch(Exception e) {  
            throw new FacesException("Error writing multimedia data"); 
     } 

}

public void crop(){
    logger.entry("PictureProvider.crop()");

    if(getCroppedImage()==null){
        return;
    }

    String filename=getCroppedImage().getOriginalFilename();

    String multimediaPath=sc.getInitParameter("multimediaPath");
    int idSpace=((Space)RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext().getFlowScope().get("selectedSpace")).getIdSpace();

    FileImageOutputStream imageOutput=null;
    File file=null;

    try{
        switch (this.getIdRequest()) {
            case "event":
                file=new File(multimediaPath + File.separator + idSpace + File.separator + "events" + File.separator
                        + spaceBo.getDao().countSectionPages(idSpace,4));

                if(file.isDirectory()){
                    int totalFiles=file.listFiles().length;

                imageOutput=new FileImageOutputStream(new File(file.getAbsolutePath()
                         + "temp_pic_" + totalFiles + ".jpg"));
                }

                //MARCAR ERRORES si no es un DIRECTORIO
                break;

            case "configuration":
                file=new File(multimediaPath + File.separator + idSpace + File.separator + "tempCrop.jpeg");
                imageOutput=new FileImageOutputStream(file);

                break;

            default:
                break;
        }


        if(imageOutput!=null){
            imageOutput.write(croppedImage.getBytes(),0,croppedImage.getBytes().length);
            imageOutput.close();
            this.setFlagCropper(false);
            this.setFlagSave(true);
        }

        RequestContext requestContext=RequestContextHolder.getRequestContext();
        RequestControlContext rec = (RequestControlContext) requestContext;

        //rec.handleEvent(new Event(this,"yes"));
    }catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
        //ARREGLAR
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found solution in an another stackoverflow [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614239/hgraphicimage-is-not-getting-refreshed-in-jsf), now every browser show right picture when I reupload these ones using ajax. This is @BalusC 's answer:

Tell the browser to not cache the image. Set the following headers on the servlet response before the first bit is ever written to its body:

```
response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate"); // HTTP 1.1.
response.setHeader("Pragma", "no-cache"); // HTTP 1.0.
response.setDateHeader("Expires", 0); // Proxies.
```

To prevent hard-nosed browsers from still caching it, add a request parameter with a timestampto the servlet URL.

```
<h:graphicImage value="imageServlet?id=#{bean.imageId}&amp;t=#{now.time}" />
```

Where `#{now}` is been registered in `faces-config.xml` as follows:

```
<managed-bean>
    <managed-bean-name>now</managed-bean-name>
    <managed-bean-class>java.util.Date</managed-bean-class>
    <managed-bean-scope>request</managed-bean-scope>
</managed-bean>
```